# Javascript Array Dynamically 

Tags: javascript

How can I create a dynamic array in an array with dynamic keys and dynamic values using javascript?

For an example, check below what I'd like:

```
Studentslist  
  Student Info 1
      "name" => "varun",
      "age" => "24"

  Student Info 2
      "name" => "Kumar",
      "age" => "25"
```

Add More Info About This Question

I have a radio buttone like this

```
<input type="radio" value="student1" id="student1" name="student1group1"/>
<input type="radio" value="student2" id="student1" name="student1group1"/>

<input type="radio" value="student3" id="student2" name="student1group2"/>
<input type="radio" value="student4" id="student2" name="student1group2"/>
```

I need to setup a  array in array when any radio button is clicked for eg in `student1group1` any of the 2 radio buttons is clicked i need to get the array like below

```
Studentslist  
  Student Info 1
          "name" => clicked value of the radio button,
```

Comment: Arrays don't have this structure in javascript.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine this is just to show you i know that array's in javascript don't have structure like that

Comment: Where are the keys and values coming from?

Comment: @DavidThomas The Keys And Value Will Be Comming From A Radio Button

Comment: Could you show us? Give us an example of what the input is, and explain what you want to happen?

Comment: @DavidThomas Kindly Check My Question I have add more info

Comment: You've got elements sharing an `id` (this is invalid HTML) and no indication of which of the `input` elements represents the age or name of the student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
var Studentslist  = [];

var student = {name:"varun", age:24 }

Studentslist.push(student);

student = {name:"Kumar", age:25};

Studentslist.push(student);

student = {name:"Varun Kumar", age:26}

Studentslist.push(student);
```

for getting student detail you can try.

```
for(var x in Studentslist)
{
    alert(x.name);
}
```

with radio buttons, you can try

```
<input type="radio" value="student1" id="student1" name="student1group1"/>
<input type="radio" value="student2" id="student1" name="student1group1"/>

<input type="radio" value="student3" id="student2" name="student1group2"/>
<input type="radio" value="student4" id="student2" name="student1group2"/>
```

javascript :

```
var Studentslist  = [];

window.onload = function(){
    var allinputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var x in allinputs)
    {
       if(x.type == "radio")
       {
          x.onclick = function() {
             if(this.checked){
               var student = {name: x.value };
               Studentslist.push(student);
             }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

You can call this method to alert.

```
function CheckStudentDetails
{
    for(var x =0;x<Studentslist.length; x++)
    {
        for(var y in Studentslist[x])
        {
             alert(Studentslist[x][y]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: how can i print all the array in a main array

Comment: @user1622904 can you explain what does it mean, ` print all the array in a main array`.

Comment: He mean how can i alert all the array in Studentslist array

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var Studentslist = [{name:"varun",age:"24"}, {name:"Kumar",age:"25"}]

alert(Studentslist.length)  //=>2

alert(Studentslist[0].name)  //=>varun

alert(Studentslist[1].age)  //=>25

Studentslist.push({name:"nickname",age:"30"})  //=>
//[{ name="varun", age="24"},{ name="Kumar", age="25"},{ name="nickname", age="30"}]
```

dynimic with JQuery (change data after each click on the checkbox)

```
var Studentslist = new Array();

$(function(){
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {          
        Studentslist[$(this).attr('name')] = {value:$(this).attr('value'), id:$(this).attr('id')}
      }
    })
})

//console.log (Studentslist['student1group1']) //=>   { value="student1", id="student1"}
//console.log (Studentslist['student1group2']) //=>   { value="student3", id="student3"}
```

Comment: is this possible to make it as  dynimic using the radio buttone

Comment: How is that nearly close to dynamic?